# PyQt5 tooltip with clickable hyperlink?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Can you suggest me a way to make hyperlink in PyQt5 tooltip clickable? Tried like this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
QtWidgets.QLabel(parent = w, text = 'Hover mouse here', toolTip = '<a href="http://google.com">Unclickable link</a>')
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

Link is visible, but not clickable, unfortunatelly.

Comment: that is not working because it just a text you have to make that as a button so that you can click that..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not an easy task to achieve.

One of the most important aspects is that users are accustomed to the conventional behavior of tool tips: if the mouse cursor hovers them (or they are clicked), they would probably disappear; this is to avoid any possibility that some important part of the widget they refer to becomes hidden (imagine a table that shows a big tooltip for a cell and hides the values of other cells that are near the first one).

Qt follows the same concepts; so, not only you can't interactively click on a tooltip, but it's usually almost impossible to hover a tooltip at all.
The only solution is to create your own tooltip.

---

In the following (rather complex) example, I'm going to show how to achieve that.
Note that this implementation is not perfect: I could test it under Linux only, but, most importantly, it's not application-wide (it *could* theoretically be possible, though).

The basic concept is to install an event filter on all widgets that could potentially have a clickable url, intercept every QEvent that is of `QEvent.ToolTip` type, and create a widget that behaves like it afterwards.

I tried to implement it as much as similar to the standard QToolTip object (which is only accessible almost by static methods). The only difference here is that the static method returns the instance, which allows to connect to the `linkActivated` signal.

```
class ClickableTooltip(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    __instance = None
    refWidget = None
    refPos = None
    menuShowing = False

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(flags=QtCore.Qt.ToolTip)
        margin = self.style().pixelMetric(
            QtWidgets.QStyle.PM_ToolTipLabelFrameWidth, None, self)
        self.setMargin(margin + 1)
        self.setForegroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText)
        self.setWordWrap(True)

        self.mouseTimer = QtCore.QTimer(interval=250, timeout=self.checkCursor)
        self.hideTimer = QtCore.QTimer(singleShot=True, timeout=self.hide)

    def checkCursor(self):
        # ignore if the link context menu is visible
        for menu in self.findChildren(
            QtWidgets.QMenu, options=QtCore.Qt.FindDirectChildrenOnly):
                if menu.isVisible():
                    return

        # an arbitrary check for mouse position; since we have to be able to move
        # inside the tooltip margins (standard QToolTip hides itself on hover),
        # let's add some margins just for safety
        region = QtGui.QRegion(self.geometry().adjusted(-10, -10, 10, 10))
        if self.refWidget:
            rect = self.refWidget.rect()
            rect.moveTopLeft(self.refWidget.mapToGlobal(QtCore.QPoint()))
            region |= QtGui.QRegion(rect)
        else:
            # add a circular region for the mouse cursor possible range
            rect = QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 16, 16)
            rect.moveCenter(self.refPos)
            region |= QtGui.QRegion(rect, QtGui.QRegion.Ellipse)
        if QtGui.QCursor.pos() not in region:
            self.hide()

    def show(self):
        super().show()
        QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().installEventFilter(self)

    def event(self, event):
        # just for safety...
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.WindowDeactivate:
            self.hide()
        return super().event(event)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        # if we detect a mouse button or key press that's not originated from the
        # label, assume that the tooltip should be closed; note that widgets that
        # have been just mapped ("shown") might return events for their QWindow
        # instead of the actual QWidget
        if source not in (self, self.windowHandle()) and event.type() in (
            QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress, QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress):
                self.hide()
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

    def move(self, pos):
        # ensure that the style has "polished" the widget (font, palette, etc.)
        self.ensurePolished()
        # ensure that the tooltip is shown within the available screen area
        geo = QtCore.QRect(pos, self.sizeHint())
        try:
            screen = QtWidgets.QApplication.screenAt(pos)
        except:
            # support for Qt < 5.10
            for screen in QtWidgets.QApplication.screens():
                if pos in screen.geometry():
                    break
            else:
                screen = None
        if not screen:
            screen = QtWidgets.QApplication.primaryScreen()
        screenGeo = screen.availableGeometry()
        # screen geometry correction should always consider the top-left corners
        # *last* so that at least their beginning text is always visible (that's
        # why I used pairs of "if" instead of "if/else"); also note that this
        # doesn't take into account right-to-left languages, but that can be
        # accounted for by checking QGuiApplication.layoutDirection()
        if geo.bottom() > screenGeo.bottom():
            geo.moveBottom(screenGeo.bottom())
        if geo.top() < screenGeo.top():
            geo.moveTop(screenGeo.top())
        if geo.right() > screenGeo.right():
            geo.moveRight(screenGeo.right())
        if geo.left() < screenGeo.left():
            geo.moveLeft(screenGeo.left())
        super().move(geo.topLeft())

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        # check the children QMenu objects before showing the menu (which could
        # potentially hide the label)
        knownChildMenus = set(self.findChildren(
            QtWidgets.QMenu, options=QtCore.Qt.FindDirectChildrenOnly))
        self.menuShowing = True
        super().contextMenuEvent(event)
        newMenus = set(self.findChildren(
            QtWidgets.QMenu, options=QtCore.Qt.FindDirectChildrenOnly))
        if knownChildMenus == newMenus:
            # no new context menu? hide!
            self.hide()
        else:
            # hide ourselves as soon as the (new) menus close
            for m in knownChildMenus ^ newMenus:
                m.aboutToHide.connect(self.hide)
                m.aboutToHide.connect(lambda m=m: m.aboutToHide.disconnect())
            self.menuShowing = False

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        # click events on link are delivered on button release!
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        self.hide()

    def hide(self):
        if not self.menuShowing:
            super().hide()

    def hideEvent(self, event):
        super().hideEvent(event)
        QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().removeEventFilter(self)
        self.refWidget.window().removeEventFilter(self)
        self.refWidget = self.refPos = None
        self.mouseTimer.stop()
        self.hideTimer.stop()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        # on some systems the tooltip is not a rectangle, let's "mask" the label
        # according to the system defaults
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOption()
        opt.initFrom(self)
        mask = QtWidgets.QStyleHintReturnMask()
        if self.style().styleHint(
            QtWidgets.QStyle.SH_ToolTip_Mask, opt, self, mask):
                self.setMask(mask.region)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        # we cannot directly draw the label, since a tooltip could have an inner
        # border, so let's draw the "background" before that
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOption()
        opt.initFrom(self)
        style = self.style()
        style.drawPrimitive(style.PE_PanelTipLabel, opt, qp, self)
        # now we paint the label contents
        super().paintEvent(event)

    @staticmethod
    def showText(pos, text:str, parent=None, rect=None, delay=0):
        # this is a method similar to QToolTip.showText;
        # it reuses an existent instance, but also returns the tooltip so that
        # its linkActivated signal can be connected
        if ClickableTooltip.__instance is None:
            if not text:
                return
            ClickableTooltip.__instance = ClickableTooltip()
        toolTip = ClickableTooltip.__instance

        toolTip.mouseTimer.stop()
        toolTip.hideTimer.stop()

        # disconnect all previously connected signals, if any
        try:
            toolTip.linkActivated.disconnect()
        except:
            pass

        if not text:
            toolTip.hide()
            return
        toolTip.setText(text)

        if parent:
            toolTip.refRect = rect
        else:
            delay = 0

        pos += QtCore.QPoint(16, 16)

        # adjust the tooltip position if necessary (based on arbitrary margins)
        if not toolTip.isVisible() or parent != toolTip.refWidget or (
            not parent and toolTip.refPos and 
            (toolTip.refPos - pos).manhattanLength() > 10):
                toolTip.move(pos)

        # we assume that, if no parent argument is given, the current activeWindow
        # is what we should use as a reference for mouse detection
        toolTip.refWidget = parent or QtWidgets.QApplication.activeWindow()
        toolTip.refPos = pos
        toolTip.show()
        toolTip.mouseTimer.start()
        if delay:
            toolTip.hideTimer.start(delay)

        return toolTip


class ToolTipTest(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        count = 1
        tip = 'This is <a href="http://test.com/{c}">link {c}</a>'
        for row in range(4):
            for col in range(4):
                button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Hello {}'.format(count))
                layout.addWidget(button, row, col)
                button.setToolTip(tip.format(c=count))
                button.installEventFilter(self)
                count += 1

    def toolTipLinkClicked(self, url):
        print(url)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.ToolTip and source.toolTip():
            toolTip = ClickableTooltip.showText(
                QtGui.QCursor.pos(), source.toolTip(), source)
            toolTip.linkActivated.connect(self.toolTipLinkClicked)
            return True
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)
```

Comment: Tried on Win 10 and Manjaro, looks nice and works fine on both. A very big "thank you" for such elaborated answer!

Comment: @StandardUser Good to know! I've updated the example code to rectify some small issues (most importantly, a correct context menu list that only includes new elements, and how it's `aboutToHide` signal behaves). That said, there will always be some platform related issue, I suggest you to try and experiment with it *a lot*!

Comment: Whatever I do I get `Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)` . Can you check your code again please?

Comment: @Harvey I don't know what you are doing, my code works fine on multiple platforms. Maybe you did something wrong instead?

Comment: Just ran across this answer from @musicamante. I wanted to say this was incredibly impressive work to do for a stranger. It's thoughtful, well communicated and works!

Comment: To use it with `QTableView` and model-view-delegate programming in general, you **must** use `installEventFilter` on the view's `viewport()`. In that case, you can't use `source.toolTip()` - that would point to the view's tooltip, not the tooltip for the item under the cursor. To get the tooltip for the item then, use the combination of `index = source.parent().indexAt(event.pos())` and `txt = source.parent().model().data(index, Qt.ToolTipRole)`.
Hope it will save you a couple hours.

Comment: @VaderB actually, installing the event filter on the viewport would return the tooltip of the *viewport*, not that of the view.

Comment: @musicamante, I know that's unexpected, but I tried it for hours - installing the filter on the view for `QTableView` catches not a single tooltip-related event. After a couple of hours of experiments and googling I found an example on a Japanese(?) website that was using `.viewport()`. That time, it worked! Try it for yourself.
I'll provide the complete solution here when I'm done with the design.

Comment: @VaderB sorry, my statement was imprecise. It will get the tooltip of the view because of the relation between the viewport and the view widget (which installs an event filter on the viewport widget). The filter *must* be set on the viewport (and it's not unexpected, as the documentation also indicates so: it's the reason for which if you want to update the content or implement `paintEvent()`, the target must be the viewport), I was only pointing out that the filter is always referred to events sent to the viewport.